# VB.net Sbyte to Byte poroblem

Tags: vb.net

Hoping someone could assist me with this.

I have the following code that returns an IP address which I got from here:

https://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions/cool_tools/reading-ldap-networkaddress-attribute-server-or-user-object/

which works perfectly in C# (Code below)

```
LdapAttribute serverNetAddr = entry.getAttribute("networkaddress");

// loop through the multivalued networkaddress field
foreach (sbyte[] addrBytes in serverNetAddr.ByteValueArray)
{

    // get the first character in the line which indicates type
    char type = (char)addrBytes[0];

    if (type == '9')
    { // only interested in TCP address
        string serverTCPAddr = "";
        for (int i = (addrBytes.Length - 4); i < addrBytes.Length; i++)
        { // last four bytes are the ip address
            byte b = unchecked((byte)addrBytes[i]); // convert sbyte to byte
            serverTCPAddr = serverTCPAddr + b; // append value to string
            if (i > 0 && i < (addrBytes.Length - 1))
                serverTCPAddr = serverTCPAddr + "."; // brute force the dots
            textBox1.Text = serverTCPAddr;
        }

    }

}
```

When I try and use the code in VB.net (see code below) It only works up until “ `For i As Integer = (addrBytes.Length - 4) To addrBytes.Length – 1`” When the code gets to “`Dim b As Byte = unchecked(CByte(addrBytes(i)))`” Then I get the following error message:

> " System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an
>   overflow."

```
    Dim serverNetAddr As LdapAttribute = entry.getAttribute("networkaddress")



    ' loop through the multivalued networkaddress field
    Dim addrBytes() As System.SByte
    For Each addrBytes In serverNetAddr.ByteValueArray

        ' get the first character in the line which indicates type
        Dim type As Char = ChrW(addrBytes(0))

        If type = "9"c Then
            ' only interested in TCP address
            Dim serverTCPAddr As String = ""
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = (addrBytes.Length - 4) To addrBytes.Length - 1
                ' last four bytes are the ip address
                '  Dim b As Byte = CType(addrBytes(i), Byte)  ' convert sbyte to byte



                Dim b As Byte = unchecked(CByte(addrBytes(i)))

                ' Dim b As SByte = unchecked(CType(addrBytes(i), Byte))  ' convert sbyte to byte
                serverTCPAddr = serverTCPAddr + b ' append value to string
                If i > 0 And i < (addrBytes.Length - 1) Then
                    serverTCPAddr = serverTCPAddr + "." ' brute force the dots
                End If
                TextBox6.Text = serverTCPAddr
            Next

        End If

    Next

End If
```

Next

I have tried “`Dim b As Byte = CByte(addrBytes(i))`” and “`Dim b As SByte = unchecked(CType(addrBytes(i), Byte))`”  ' `convert sbyte to byte` 
to no avail, it keeps crashing on Dim b As Byte section.

Can anyone tell me why it works in C# and not VB.net and possibly a way to fix it?

Thank you,
Regards,
Zain Peters

Comment: I don't think `unchecked` work in VB.NET like in C# - you likely suppress the overflow error in your C# version. you could use TRY/CATCH in your VB.NET version to catch the overflow

Comment: VB.NET always checks for overflow by default.  And will complain when the sbyte is less than 0.  That cannot be turned off for a single statement like it can in C#, it is a compile option.  Project > Properties > Compile tab > Advanced button > Remove integer overflow checks checkbox.   Or keep the code in a C# library, taking advantage of the excellent language interop in .NET is never a bad idea.

Comment: A user by the name Viorel_ solved the problem over here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e68f6c5-0e60-4c1f-bcd4-c7aad97e83fb/vbnet-sbyte-to-byte-poroblem?forum=vbgeneral

Dim sb As SByte

    Dim b As Byte

    sb = -2

    b = CByte(sb And &HFF) ' result: 254

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

A user by the name Viorel_ solved the problem over here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e68f6c5-0e60-4c1f-bcd4-c7aad97e83fb/vbnet-sbyte-to-byte-poroblem?forum=vbgeneral

Dim sb As SByte

```
Dim b As Byte

sb = -2

b = CByte(sb And &HFF) ' result: 254
```

Thank you everyone!